# Can't resize uploaded image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm using paperclip gem for uploading and resizing images. This setup works fine. I'm able to display the uploaded images. The problem comes when I try to resize the uploaded image.

Here is snippet from the model file

```
has_attached_file :photo,
                  :size => {:small => "150x150>"}
```

When I try to upload the image I get this error.

```
Photo /var/folders/gm/gm-SegRMHuOkSlYtTMkO8U+++TI/-Tmp-/file.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

I'm sure that the file is jpg. Here is the output of the file command

```
file.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, comment: "CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJ"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but in our application we do the same thing and it works. Our code looks like this:

```
    has_attached_file :image,
             :styles => {:small => "280x173#", :medium => "635x393#"},
             :convert_options => {:all => "-quality 80"},#, 
             :default_style => :medium,
             :default_url => "/images/study/nophoto.jpg"

    validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 10.megabyte
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ['image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/x-png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/jpg']
```

The difference I see, is that you might have to provide convert_options to be able to resize.

Comment: With the code that you suggest I get the same error described above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any other jpg file, maybe with a simpler path also?

Comment: and, did it work? I suppose not, could you provide more of the error message, maybe anything in the logs? It worked for me - imagemagick installation working - with this:

      has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

Comment: As far as I read it is configuration issue, not a Rails or paperclip problem